# Google login with Firebase Invalid Idp Response

Tags: android, exception, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am currently converting my old Google Plus login code to the new way.
I find it very very hard to understand the basic principles. And it wont work.

First step is explaining how to get signing in working:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Second step is Firebase. For some reason you need to combine above documentation with the following:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Why is that exactly? It seems so overly complicated for its purpose: just signing in. 
Anyway. You have to do the following:

In the `onCreate` of your Activity you need to add:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(webClientId)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .enableAutoManage(mContext /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

In your login click handler you add

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
mActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

In the `onActivityResult` you have to add

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
     GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken(), null);
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(mActivity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            //do something

                        }
                    });

        }
```

Here I get an exception when calling GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential with getIdToken.

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid Idp Response: the Google id_token is not allowed to be used with this application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com, which is not authorized to be used in the project with project_number: xxxxxxxxxxxx.

just printing out the token with

> result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken();
>   works fine.

I am almost sure that this `web_client_id` is correct, because when I replace it the initial login request will fail.

I checked the Firebase console under auth -> google -> Web SDK configuration.
The Webclient-ID and secret matches those in the Google console webapp client id.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after spending some hours on it i decided to get rid of all the firebase related stuff. Now it works. Don't get why your would need that firebase stuff anyway.

For logging in i have the following:

in your activity or activityFragment add:

```
private static Activity mActivity;
private FragmentActivity mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleSignInResult cachedSignInResult;
private String webClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(webClientId)
                .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .enableAutoManage(mContext /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
}
```

Add logic for handling login requests.

```
public void requestLogin(OnLoginCompleteListener onLoginCompleteListener) {

    Log.d(TAG,"request login");

    //already logged in scenarios
    if (isConnected() && cachedSignInResult != null){
        Log.d(TAG,"you are already logged in with "+cachedSignInResult.getDisplayName());
        onLoginCompleteListener.onLoginSuccess()
        return;
    }
    else if (isConnected()){
        Log.d(TAG,"already connected, but no ");
        silentLogin(onLoginCompleteListener);
        return;
    }

    forceRegularLogin(onLoginCompleteListener);
}


public boolean isConnected() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null){
        Log.d(TAG,"cannot check isConnected without api client");
        return false;
    }
    return mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
}

private void silentLogin(final OnLoginCompleteListener onLoginCompleteListener){

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult =
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult   googleSignInResult) {

            if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()){
                Log.d(TAG,"result is ok with name "+googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount().getDisplayName());
                cachedSignInResult = googleSignInResult;
                onLoginCompleteListener.onLoginSuccess()
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"not logged in silently. do regular login");
                requestLogin(onLoginCompleteListener);
            }
        }
    });
}


private void forceRegularLogin(OnLoginCompleteListener onLoginCompleteListener){
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null){
        Log.d(TAG,"cannot login in. no google api client");
        onLoginCompleteListener.error("no_google_api_client_found");
        return;
    }

    registeredLoginCallback = onLoginCompleteListener; //register for later use in activity result

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

add onActivityResult callback.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"on activity result");

    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

    if (result.isSuccess()){

        if (registeredLoginCallback != null) {
            registeredLoginCallback.onLoginSuccess();
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG,"no callback registered for logging in result ok");
        }
    }
    else{
        if (registeredLoginCallback != null) {
            registeredLoginCallback.error();
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG,"no callback registered for logging in result error");
        }
    }
}
```

add interface for complete callbacks

```
public interface OnLoginCompleteListener{
     public void onLoginSuccess();
     public void error(String message);
}
```

now in your login button callback you add

```
 requestLogin(new OnLoginCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoginSuccess() {
          Log.d(TAG,"logged in");
      }
      @Override
      public void error(String message) {
          Log.d(TAG,"error logging in"+message);
      }
 }
```

In addition you can add the following method and interface to get user profile information

```
public void requestCurrentPerson(final OnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener onRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener) {

    Log.d(TAG,"request current person");

    silentLogin(new OnLoginCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess(i) {

            SocialPerson socialPerson = new SocialPerson();
            socialPerson.id = signInResult.getSignInAccount().getId();
            socialPerson.name = signInResult.getSignInAccount().getDisplayName();
            socialPerson.avatarURL = signInResult.getSignInAccount().getPhotoUrl().toString();
            onRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener.onRequestSocialPersonSuccess(socialPerson);
        }

        @Override
        public void error(String message) {
            onRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener.error("error_fetching_social_person "+message);
        }
    });
}


public interface OnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener {

    public void onRequestSocialPersonSuccess(SocialPerson socialPerson);
    public void error(String message);
}
```

After logging in you would call

```
requestCurrentPerson(new OnRequestSocialPersonCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRequestSocialPersonSuccess( SocialPerson socialPerson) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"this is my persoin "+socialPerson);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void error(Message message) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"error_fetching_social_person " +message);
                    }
}
```